# Moving SubSites by preserving GUID's

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm trying to move a Sharepoint Subsite into another one using the **stsadm export** and then **import**.

After the import, the site is working, except that I'm using some XSLT on some pages.  The XSLT datasources are bounded to the lists GUIDs.  And when importing it re-generates a new GUID for everything.

Is there a way to preserve the GUIDs when importing a site?  Or is there any method out there instead of using stsadm export/import?

Any help appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution... I used the **Gary Lapointe extensions for stsadm**.

In the function "**gl-import2**" function there is a "**retainobjectidentity**" parameter to persist the GUIDs through the import process.

Here's the link to the function :
http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2007/10/better-import.html

Answer (score 1):

Convert listview web parts to xslt based webparts in place of using DVWP.

Comment: but isn't there any way to maintain GUIDs through and export/import operation?

Comment: thats not possible GUIDS are unique if you try preserve them their are chances of duplication

Comment: when ever i create a site template i convert list views to xslt based webparts rather than using DVWP